# How to publish a desktop application to another computer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I wrote the first desktop application in Flutter, how can I get the things I need to run this application on another computer?

I found the Release folder (build\windows\runner\Release) with the following contents:

[Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8mMO.png)

But when I try to run the app, I only see a black screen.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://flutter.dev/desktop#distribution)

Answer (score 0):

Download Visual Studio 2019 or later it is required.

Download here
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&channel=Release&source=VSLandingPage&cid=2110&workload=dotnet-cpluscplus

— If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)

then run one of following command in your project diroctory

- flutter build windows

Then go to the release folder you should see the .exe file

Comment: Why is visual studio required?